# get value from select cell in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I make a select_tag to select value:

```
#index
 <%= form_tag com_port_setting_write_path do %>
            <%= select_tag "dropdown_cases[]", options_for_select([ ["6 Bottles", 1], ["12 Bottles", 2], ["18 Bottles", 3], ["24 Bottles", 4], ["30 Bottles", 5], ["36 Bottles", 6], ["42 Bottles", 7]]) %>
            <%= submit_tag "Setting",:class => "btn btn-primary offset4" %>
            <%end%>
<%end%>


#controller
def index

end

def com_port_setting_write
    params["dropdown_cases"].each do |cases|
        @this_is_the_dropdown_value = cases.to_i
        puts @this_is_the_dropdown_value
    end
    render :com_port_setting
end
```

It work fine but I want to change it to get value from select cell in table, how can I do that

edit: I want create a table and get value from select cell and I don't know how to do that

Comment: You will need to write more precisely what you need. `but I want to change it` - change what? `select cell in table` - what table?

Comment: What table are you referring to? Is this a table in the database? If so, what is the name of that table and its corresponding model?

Comment: You want to select something something and render a table dynamically filtering what you selected?

Comment: No, I want to select cell in table and get value of that cell